# Script batch que agregue contenidos desde un txt a otro

Tags: cmd, batch, línea-de-comandos

Estoy intentando hacer un merge entre 2 archivos txt agregando campos que el txtPrincipal no contiene desde el txtSecundario:

```
txtPrincipal:
hola=hello
mi casa=my house
amigo=friend

txtSecundario:
amigo=friend
mi casa=home
perro=dog
```

El resultado deberia contar con los valores del txtSecundario que no esten en el txtPrincipal sin sobreescribir los casos en que el valor antes del "=" sea el mismo (por ejemplo no se debería cambiar en el TxtResultadoel valor de "mi casa=my house" y tampoco se deberia agregar una nueva linea "mi casa=home")

```
TxtResultado:
hola=hello
mi casa= my house
amigo=friend
perro=dog
```

Hasta ahora he logrado obtener los campos que necesito en un igualdades.txt que uso como auxiliar:

```
@ECHO OFF
del TxtResultado.txt
FOR /F "delims==" %%A IN (txtPrincipal.txt) DO echo %%A >> txtPrincipalAux.txt
FOR /F "delims==" %%A IN (txtSecundario.txt) DO echo %%A >> txtSecundarioAux.txt
findstr /xg:txtSecundarioAux.txt txtPrincipalAux.txt > igualdades.txt 

igualdades.txt:<br>
amigo<br>
casa<br>
```

Lo que necesito ahora es obtener los campos del txtSecundario que no se encuentren en el igualdades.txt y generar un nuevo archivo para luego agregarlos al txtPrincipal

```
FOR /F "delims==" %%A IN (txtSecundario.txt) DO (  
  /*bool= false*/
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%B IN (igualdades.txt) DO (
        If == %%A EQU %%B (/*bool = true*/)
    )
    If /*!bool, agregar la linea al txtresultado*/
)
```

Queda por resolver las lineas `/**/` y otro problema que se me presenta es con los espacios al momento del `"If == %%A EQU %%B"`, las variables quedan con espacios al final y no cumplen con el criterio del `if` aunque los caracteres sean iguales.

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar el problema de los espacios al comparar las variables en el bucle, puedes usar la expansión de variables para eliminar los espacios adicionales. Además, puedes utilizar una variable booleana para determinar si encontraste una coincidencia en el bucle interior. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías hacerlo:

```
@ECHO OFF
del TxtResultado.txt
FOR /F "delims==" %%A IN (txtPrincipal.txt) DO echo %%A >> txtPrincipalAux.txt
FOR /F "delims==" %%A IN (txtSecundario.txt) DO echo %%A >> txtSecundarioAux.txt
findstr /xg:txtSecundarioAux.txt txtPrincipalAux.txt > igualdades.txt
FOR /F "delims==" %%A IN (txtSecundario.txt) DO (
    SET "encontrado=false"
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%B IN (igualdades.txt) DO (
        SET "campoSecundario=%%A"
        SET "campoEnIgualdades=%%B"
        SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
        IF !campoSecundario! EQU !campoEnIgualdades! (
            SET "encontrado=true"
        )
        ENDLOCAL
    )
    IF NOT !encontrado! (
        echo %%A >> TxtResultado.txt
    )
)
```

Este script utiliza la expansión de variables `!variable!` para eliminar los espacios adicionales al comparar las variables `campoSecundario` y `campoEnIgualdades`. Además, se utiliza la variable `encontrado` para determinar si se ha encontrado una coincidencia durante el bucle interno. Si no se encuentra ninguna coincidencia, se agrega la línea al archivo `TxtResultado.txt`